# IPython notebook: How to write cell magic which can access notebook variables?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

My question is: How can I write an IPython cell magic which has access to the namespace of the IPython notebook?

IPython allows writing user-defined cell magics. My plan is creating a plotting function which can plot one or multiple arbitrary Python expressions (expressions based on Pandas Series objects), whereby each line in the cell string is a separate graph in the chart.

This is the code of the cell magic:

```
def p(line, cell):
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    line_list = cell.split('\n')

    counter = 0
    for line in line_list:
        df['series' + str(counter)] = eval(line)      
        counter += 1

    plt.figure(figsize = [20,6])
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    df.plot(ax = ax)


def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    ipython.register_magic_function(p, 'cell')
```

The function receives the entire cell contents as a string. This string is then split by line breaks and evaluated using eval(). The result is added to a Pandas DataFrame. Finally the DataFrame is plotted using matplotlib.

Usage example: First define the Pandas Series object in IPython notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Series([1,2,3])
```

Then call the magic in IPython notebook (whereby the whole code below is one cell):

```
%%p
ts * 3
ts + 1
```

This code fails with the following error:

```
NameError: name 'ts' is not defined
```

I suspect the problem is that the `p` function only receives `ts * 3\n ts + 1` as a string and that it does not have access to the `ts` variable defined in the namespace of IPython notebook (because the `p` function is defined in a separate .py file).

How does my code have to be changed so the cell magic has access to the `ts` variable defined in the IPython notebook (and therefore does not fail with the NameError)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`@needs_local_scope` decorator](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magic.html#IPython.core.magic.needs_local_scope) decorator. Documentation is a bit missing, but you can see [how it is used](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/23fb4ff6343e32b9d1921af4f9f1c58ffadd3376/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L1063-L1084), and contributing to docs would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `shell.user_ns` from [`Magics`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magic.html#IPython.core.magic.Magics). For example something like:

```
from IPython.core.magic import Magics

class MyClass(Magics):
    def myfunc(self):
        print(self.shell.user_ns)
```

See how it's used in code examples: [here](https://github.com/danielballan/bluesky/blob/master/bluesky/magics.py#L61) and [here](https://github.com/iamaziz/iversions/blob/master/iversions/iversions.py#L68).