# IPython - importing/populating namespace with custom magic

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

The `%pylab` magic in IPython imports a bunch of functions into the user's workspace, which is very convenient.  Looking at the code, it's not at all obvious how this is done.  What I have so far is a magic function in my startup folder:

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic

@register_line_magic
def import_my_functions(line):
    """
    Import functions into namespace somehow....
    e.g. import numpy as np
    """
```

It then should be possible:

```
In[1]: %import_my_functions
 imported the following:
   numpy as np
   .....
In[2]: np
Out[2]: <module 'numpy' from ..../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>
```

Bonus would be if the command also reloads changed modules.

Answer (score 3):

Advice 1: [Don't](http://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.html)  use `%pylab`.

Advice 2: don't try to imitate pylab usage it will bite you

If you want to have convenient import create your own package and do `from mypackage import *`

If you really want a magic that have access to python namespace you should see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28652753/ipython-notebook-how-to-write-cell-magic-which-can-access-notebook-variables/28652990#28652990). and add the `@needs_local_scope` decorator.

Comment: I've been using `from mypackage import *` but it lacks certain things.  (1) It cannot reload changed modules.  (2) It won't let me define things differently based on an argument (e.g., I'd like to define a "redraw" function differently based on whether I've specified inline plotting or not.  (3) I cannot invoke other magics (like the mysterious `%matplotlib inline`) from the import.

Comment: Fair enough for (1) though, you could probably have a function that takes arguments, go up one frame and modify globals. But that might be a bit too hackish.